How does the Shapechange spell interact with augmentations?
How does the Shapechange spell interact with cyberware and bioware in 5th edition Shadowrun?
The spell description reads;

Shapechange transforms a voluntary subject into  a normal
(non-paranormal) critter, though the subject  retains human
consciousness. The subject can only assume the form of a critter
whose base Body Rating is 2  points greater or less than her own.
Consult the Critters  section, (p. 392, SR5) for the subject’s
Physical attributes  while in critter form. Add 1 to the critter’s
Base attribute  Ratings for every hit the caster generates. Her Mental
attributes remain unchanged. This spell does not transform clothing
and equipment. Magicians in critter form can still cast spells but
cannot perform tasks requiring speech. The subject may  not turn into
a swarm.

There seems to be no restrictions on the use of this spell on characters with cyberware or bioware. The spell itself does not discuss how it interacts with augmentations, only saying that it 'does not transform clothing and equipment.'
I would assume that the spell does not just remove the augmentations from the character. However, nothing I can find in the spell, the spell errata, or the base description of manipulation spells describes the interaction.
Cyberware is, presumably, a form of equipment and would not be altered. After all, cyberware can quite literally be just a gun attached to your shoulder, and presumably a gun does not stop being "equipment" because you welded it to your shoulder.
Bioware is part of the creature, so presumably it would be transformed by the spell. However, the spell does not discuss if the character maintains the benefits of the bioware while transformed.
Does cyberware stay attached? If the character has a cyber arm and transforms into a shark, do they become a shark with a cyber arm? If so, does the cyber arm replace a fin, or is it just attached to the side of their body?
If the character has bioware that impacts their physical attributes, does that bioware just stop functioning while they are transformed? If not, are the changes added to the critters attributes?
Is the answer different for bioware that augments mental stats, as the spell says the character transformed maintains their mental attributes?
Specific answers with sources would be best, but I would also except information about how similar situations are handled by the system. If other editions address this issue that information could also be helpful, in absence of any other information.

Cyberware are Augmentations and are part of you
You paid Essence to gain Cyberware and Bioware. As such, they have become you of sorts, they modify you.

Attributes boosted by cyberware or bioware do
not affect the calculation for things such as points for
Knowledge skills or Contacts. However, other in-game
mechanics such as Initiative and Inherent Limits are
modified by these augmentations, which means these
bonuses need to be factored in during Step Eight: Final
Numbers (p. 100). When calculating the Social limit using
Essence, round your remaining Essence up to the
nearest whole number before calculating the limit1

Cyberware also exists for critters. However the spell is silent if it keeps item cyber or temporarily replaces them
As such, if you transform Bob the Troll with a cyber arm into a black bear, it will result in one of two things, depending on the Gamemaster:

a black bear with normal arms for the duration of the spell.
a black bear with a black bear cyber arm for the duration of the spell.

The cyberware might be treated cosmetic or working as intended, depending on GM.



In either case, after the spell ends, all cyberware and bioware will be in the same state as before, and neither you, nor the cyberware should not receive damage from the spell - that is not part of the spell as described.
But Shifters...
NO! Read carefully and you will easily note that the Shapechange spell is clearly different from the Shift (Human) Critter Power of Shapeshifters, which explicitly destroys Cyber- and Bioware.
In 4th Edition, the rules about Shifters explicitly rejected (and healed!) away such items, unless they were Critter Deltaware, which would vanish while looking human:3

Augmentations
Most enhancement technologies available to metahumans
are also available to animals at similar Essence and nuyen costs.
Shapeshifter characters, however, face several disadvantages
when considering augmentation: their Regeneration power
heals incisions rapidly, Shift rejects any foreign matter, and any
loss of Essence will cause them to lose Magic—which could
potentially cause them to be stuck in critter form permanently.
Modern science can circumvent certain of these restrictions
using specially-formulated materials and surgical techniques—
for a price.
In practice, this means that shapeshifters can only accept
deltaware implants, and only in their natural animal forms.  ese
implants do not carry over to their human form, but they don’t
disappear either—they’re simply not available while the character
is in human form.

If anything, this actually could also serve as an argument for the hammerspace (e.g. transform to normal parts), as the only cyberware that Shifters can get at all (Delta) is hammerspaced on using their Shift power.

Fourth Edition

Shapechange transforms a voluntary subject into a normal (non-paranormal)
critter, though the subject retains human consciousness. The
subject can only assume the form of a critter whose base Body rating
is 2 points greater or less than her own. Consult the Critters section,
p. 292, for the subject’s Physical attributes while in critter form. Add 1
to the critter’s Base attribute Ratings for every hit the caster generates.
Her Mental attributes remain unchanged.2

The wording is 1:1 identical, so we can look at old discussions, because the wording has been a problem before:

On Reddit people generally seem to agree that treating it as not transforming cyberware in any way is stupid, it would deal damage, which the spell doesn't. The two dominant way to handle it in that discussion was temporary Hammerspace.
Dumpshock refers to an old FAQ document:


Mooncrow
I don't think so - from the FAQ (the evil one):
While in critter form the character loses access to any abilities and powers particular to their normal physical form (e.g., natural low-light vision, natural armor, cyberware, etc.) and gains any of the critter's Powers (Enhanced Senses, Natural Weapon, etc.) while they are in that form.

So... we need an SR4 FAQ from about 2010... And I found a slightly younger version from 2012, from the official page even, and it has 3 notes on Shapechange:

Does the Shapechange/(Critter Form) spell grant the target character the critter’s powers?
Yes. While in critter form the character loses access to any abilities and powers particular to their normal physical form (e.g., natural low-light vision, natural armor, cyberware, etc.) and gains any of the critter’s Powers (Enhanced Senses, Natural Weapon, etc.) while they are in that form.
Can an adept or mystic adept use their adept powers while under the effects of the Shapechange/(Critter) Form spell? How does Killing Hands work with the Natural Weapon power?
Yes, an adept or mystic adept retains the use of their adept powers while in critter form. Natural Weapon is an Unarmed Combat attack, so powers that enhance such attacks (e.g., Killing Hands, Critical Strike, Distance Strike, Elemental Strike, etc.) work normal.
Can you change your gender with the Shapechange/(Critter) Form spell?
The Shapechange spell doesn’t generally specify the sex or other physical aspects of the subject beyond the change in species. In the past some Shadowrun material has suggested such changes are possible, and players and gamemasters are welcome to include that as an option in their games if they so choose.


1 - SR5 Core Rules, p.95.
2 - SR4A Core Rules, p.211.
3 - SR4 Runner's Companion, p.87/88

Your conclusion does not seem to follow from your evidence. The spell itself certain does not say that your cyberware is transformed, nor does anything in what you quoted. Just because you paid essence doesn't make the item part of your character; If it did, then if the item were removed, you would get the essence back. You don't. If anything, the rule you quoted-the shift critter power shapeshifters get-would imply the opposite of your conclusion, as it's the closest equivalent in the game to the shapechange spell. It's magic transforming you into another form

@Necroes the spell does not say it is expelled, so it doesn't.

Trish: No one said it did. The shift power doesn't even say it expels them, just that they're rejected and 'lost,' resulting in a large amount of damage. The implication being that the augmentations are destroyed during the process, not removed.

@Necroes If you look for old editions, it was worded that they were pushed out consistently starting in 3rd ed, when shapechangers appeared first.

@Necroes I unearthed the SR4 FAQ which should settle it, even made me swap around the order of options^^

Looking at the FAQ, there is evidence under the question on enchanting cyberware to back up your claim that cyberware once installed is considered part of the creature, even for magical purposes. However, under the question on the increase/decrease[attribute] spell, it is stated that you can only enhance cyberware with cyberware enhancements, definitely implying magic can not be used to change cyberware into cyberware with claws. So it would seem the answer is that, like the rest of the body of the creature, when shapechanged-not shifted-cyberware is just held in a manner of hammerspace.

@Necroes that's why I gave the "GM decides, these two here are the options to choose from sensibly"
